# Updating DataGridView After row search result

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very basic question I want to update DataGridView using this code

```
private void updateDGV1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
        // open connection to database 
        try
        {

            cmbl1 = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(datadp1);
            datadp1.Update(ds1, "PlotDetails");
            MessageBox.Show("Information Updated", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            load_table();
            AutoCompleteSizeSearch();
            AutoCompletePlotSearch();
            AutoCompleteOwnerSearch();
            AutoCompleteLocatoinSearch();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

After search for a result using this code

```
  private void plots_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt1);
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("D_ID LIKE '%{0}' AND Area LIKE '%{1}' AND Cat LIKE '%{2}' AND PBS LIKE '%{3}%' AND Name LIKE '%{4}%' AND Size LIKE '%{5}%' AND Location LIKE '%{6}%' AND PlotNo LIKE '%{7}%'", dids_combo.Text, areacs_txt.Text, categorycs_txt.Text, phblses_txt.Text, owners_txt.Text, sizes_txt.Text, locations_txt.Text, plots_txt.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

After getting result of search I couldn't been able to update searched result.
updateDGV1_Click works fine on the whole DGV but not on Searched result like in below image
[After search,result not updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqaVp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend using the TableAdapter to communicate with your database instead of generating a connection in that fashion. This will also allow you to easily update your DataGridView with the contents of the TableAdpater Query (Search) that you want to preform. I wish I could go into more detail but I'm in a hurry at the moment I will provide links explaining this better below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx

I personally use TableAdapters to connect databases in my projects, but I have found a solution that may also allow you to keep your code the way it is for the most part.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14249/How-to-populate-DataGridView-GridView-with-SQL-sta

What you will need to do when you want to preform a search on the current working DataSet. This code is an example I haven't tested it.

```
string conn_str = "Data Source=dbServer;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=True";
string sql_str = “select * from table1”;

SqlDataAdapter data_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_str, conn_str);
SqlCommandBuilder cmd_builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(data_adapter);

// Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
// This line populates our new table with the data from our sql query
data_adapter.Fill(table);
db_binding_source.DataSource = table;

// Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
data_grid_view.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
// you can make it grid readonly.
data_grid_view.ReadOnly = true; 
// finally bind the data to the grid
data_grid_view.DataSource = db_binding_source;
```

Here is also another answer on SO similar to what you're asking
[How do I Update/Reload DataGridView BindingSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020384/how-do-i-update-reload-datagridview-bindingsource)

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Buy I am sorry this won't help in my current context .I have a very simple question can we update Dataview dv result after search with update DataGridView Code?